# Extract values from arrays and return it nicely into html table

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I am having a code like this:

```
$Query->GetPlayers( );
```

and it would return an array like that:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 0
            [Name] => Player 1
            [Frags] => 0
            [Time] => 27537
            [TimeF] => 07:38:57
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 0
            [Name] => Player 2
            [Frags] => 0
            [Time] => 8779
            [TimeF] => 02:26:19
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 0
            [Name] => Player 3
            [Frags] => 0
            [Time] => 8121
            [TimeF] => 02:15:21
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 0
            [Name] => Player 4
            [Frags] => 0
            [Time] => 7430
            [TimeF] => 02:03:50
        )
)
```

Now I want to extract "Name" and "TimeF" of each player and put it in a table like this:

Player | Time played
Player1 | 07:38:57
Player2 | ...
Player3 | ...

etc.

Could you please help me? I have no idea how to get those values with a foreach statement.

Comment: That table should actually be one line per player, not all added behind each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for something like this, I'd use a foreach like so:

```
foreach($Query->GetPlayers( ) as $player){
   $name = $player["name"];
   $time = $player["TimeF"];
   //do what you need to do with the data above, here
}
```

Comment: I will give this a try - thank you very much !!

Comment: No problem! Be sure to mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: Nope @JayBlanchard , part of stackoverflow is to give the OP a chance learn how to do things him/herself by giving them a jump off point :-)

Comment: I just figured that since you wrote part of the code for the OP you would write the rest. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ SO is about people showing effort and getting help.

Comment: Its fine, the table i can do myself :) thanks guys. its working. Will mark the answer as accepted.